# Пользовательский скрипт и Mixed Content в GoogleChrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Пишу пользовательский скрипт для Google Chrome. Скрипт запускается на странице пример `https://example.com/` после чего происходит ajax запрос json объекта с другого сервера `пример http://server.com/`. В Google Chrome пишет при попытке отправить запрос:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://server.com/'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Я прекрасно понимаю что все из-за разных протоколов `https://` и `http://`. Но на сервере нет `https://` перелинковки и к серверу доступа нет.

Если Google Chrome нажать на щиток и разрешить отправку скрипта все будет работать. Но каждый раз так делать это не удобно. Есть ли вариант как-то обмануть это все.

**UPDATE**

```
   if (/https:\/\/server.com\/boo\/index.do/.test(w.location.href)) {
       /*Для запуска скрипта на нужной странице*/

 var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
            var xhr = new XHR();

            xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/Num='+ w.pknum, true);


                xhr.onload = function() {
                x = this.responseText;
                w.jsin = JSON.parse(x);
                console.log(w.jsin);
                Createhtml(topaz,w.jsin,DOC);

                }
                xhr.onerror = function() {
                alert( 'Ошибка ' + this.status );
                }

                xhr.send();
```

Добавление запроса. Добавил не весь скрипт а сам запрос ибо сам скрипт громадный.

Comment: получается что к вашему скрипту навязываются дополнительные требования, что мол его можно запускать только на сайтах с https

Comment: Пробовал тут тоже убрать https(`if (/https:\/\/server.com\/boo\/index.do/.test(w.location.href)) {`), все равно шлет с https

Answer (score 1):

Пишите урлы без указания протокола, вместо `https://` или `http://` указывайте `//:`

Comment: Если в запросе не указать `http:` то он начинает слать запрос с `https:`. Так скрипт запускается `https://example.com/`. Соответственно запрос будет не на `http://server.com/`, а на `https://server.com/`. А так как на сервере нет перелинковки, то ответ выдаст ошибку подключения. 
Нужен другой вариант

Comment: надо бы скрипт смотреть, а так гадать только остается что вы там делаете. И что за перелинковка такая..., это термин вообще то из SEO

Comment: Добавил запрос. Про перелинковку сори, редирект имел ввиду с `https://` на `http://`